# How can I use a Gson string to create an array of strings for each type?

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

My goal is to import a JSON file, and for each element of the JSON object I want to create an array for each type of that element.  If this doesn't make sense, then what I wish to do is the following:

Given the following text within the JSON file:

```
...,
{
"baseLevel": 50,
"difficulty": 233,
"durability": 80,
"level": 70,
"maxQuality": 2921,
"name": {
  "de": "Trauzeugen-Jacke",
  "en": "Best Man's Jacket",
  "fr": "Veste de témoin",
  "ja": "??????????"
        },
"stars": 2
}
,...
```

I have a large number of entries within my JSON file containing the above information, what I was hoping to do was create an array for each type, such as baseLevel, difficulty, durability, level, maxQuality and name(en), however I am completely lost at how to do this.

My setup at the moment is(using GSON):

```
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(in);
prettyJson[i] = gson.toJson(jsonElement);
```

I'm not sure whether I am meant to be using the jsonElement or prettyJson[] to construct the array I wish to create, let alone how.  I've tried doing some research but havn't had any luck or found any examples that appear to relate to what I am trying to do.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or provide an example of how to go about achieving my goal that would be great.

Thanks all!

**Edit1:**
I believe I have fixed my first issue and have created a JsonElement containing all of the "en" fields through the code below:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(in);
JsonArray recipe_array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();
for (Object o : recipe_array) {
    JsonObject recipe = (JsonObject) o;
    JsonElement names = recipe.get("name");
    String names_s = names.toString();
    JsonElement names_e = parser.parse(names_s).getAsJsonObject().get("en");
    System.out.println(names_e);

}
```

I am now not sure how to convert this into a String Array (if it's even possible?) since I get an exception error when trying to convert names_e into a JsonArray.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can achieve this in one step. You could iterate over the array you got and pull the specific value out to store in a new array. Like the following.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyItemList myItemList = gson.fromJson(jsonFile, myItemList.class);

for (Item item : myItemList.getItems) {
    baseLevelArrayList.add(item.getBaseLevel);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is MyItemList a specific class? Because I'm not sure how to apply it?

Comment: MyItemList would be the class for your root object. Just a class with one ArrayList holding all your items.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up searching around and managed to convert the first set into a string, and re-parse that into an object which I then selected just the "en" section.  From this I was able to convert it into a string array which was used to fill my dropdown menus.